# Return Variable After Running forEach

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, adonis.js

i just recently try learn nodejs, i choose adonisjs framework, because i think it's will be easier for me to learn, because on the nutshell have some similarities with laravel, which i used to code with.

but now, i have some problem, i can't solve, i have function like this :

```
  async getAllPeople() {
    let allPeople = await People.all()
    let myArray = []
    let checkChild = async (people) => {
      let eachPeopleChild = await people.children().fetch()
      if (eachPeopleChild.rows.length > 0) {
        return people
      }
      return false
    }
    allPeople.rows.forEach(async (people) => {
      let res = await checkChild(people)
      if (res !== false) {
        myArray.push(res)
      }
    })
    console.log(myArray)
  }
```

when i run this function, it's show an empty array `[]`, i know because of nodejs or js actually have asynchronous behavior, it run this : `console.log(myArray)` first

what i expected is, how to execute, or return `myArray` after all the looping or other process is done?

-- problem is on the way i loop the array is not on the way i made callback, promise, because i already using `async - await` which is returning promise and it's behavior. `map` or  `forEach` does not allow what i expected.. and the solution is clear : `for ( item of items )`

thank you

Comment: yes, but when i read the link you gave, lead me to another confusion, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i just found the solution, thx for the guy at the other place that told me, that i can't use `forEach` and just use `for (let item of anArray)` instead.
here is my code now :

```
  async getAllPeople() {
    let allPeople = await People.all()
    let myArray = []
    let checkChild = async (people) => {
      let eachPeopleChild = await people.children().fetch()
      if (eachPeopleChild.rows.length > 0) {
        return people
      }
      return false
    }

    for (let people of allPeople.rows) {
      let res = await checkChild(people)
      if (res !== false) {
        myArray.push(res)
      }
    }
    return myArray
  }
```

everyhing works now..!!

Comment: You could even do `for (const people of ...)` since `people`'s reference is never reassigned within the loop. You should get in the habit of using `const` when you don't plan to change the variable's reference, or its value if it's a primitive. e.g. `const allPeople`, `const myArray`, `const checkChild`, `const eachPeopleChild` and `const res`